# Can't run XML::LibXML on Strawberry Perl - invalid path in Dynaloader.pm

Tags: perl, xml-libxml

I've just installed Strawberry Perl on a new computer, and installed XML::LibXML through cpan (I think it was already installed). When I try to run a script calling LibXML, I get the following error message:

> Can't load 'C:\Strawberry\perl\vendor\lib/auto/XML/LibXML/LibXML.xs.dll' for module XML::LibXML: load_file:The specified path is invalid at C:/strawberry/perl/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 193.   at C:\Strawberry\perl\vendor\lib/XML/LibXML.pm line 156. BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:\Strawberry\perl\vendor\lib/XML/LibXML.pm  line 156.

This is similar to [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11468141/cant-load-c-strawberry-perl-site-lib-auto-xml-libxml-libxml-dll-for-module-x?newreg=a50a146fc7284999b6d4935909571ccb), but the error is slightly different, and I've tried all the advice given in that post but still get the message.

- LibXML.xs.dll is in the path given above
- C:\strawberry\c\bin is in the path
- I've created the perl5lib system variable, and set it to C:\Strawberry\perl\vendor\lib (C:\Strawberry\perl\site\lib was empty)
- libxml2-2___.dll is in c:\strawberry\c\bin

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Did you use the Strawberry CPAN client and do you have the output of the compile?

Comment: Yes, I used the Strawberry CPAN client - by 'output of the compile', do you mean what is sent to the command line, or is an output stored in a file somewhere?

Comment: He's referring to the output the command sent to the console.

Comment: Thanks - then I didn't record it, no. If I try to install it again, I just get the message that it's up to date (2.0124).

Comment: @DomGlennon There should be a build log, something like `C:\strawberry\cpan\build\XML-LibXML-2.0124`

Comment: I've uninstalled Strawberry and reinstalled, but I get the same result. This is what I get from CPAN when installing LibXML:`Fetching with LWP:
http://cpan.strawberryperl.com/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
Fetching with LWP:
http://cpan.strawberryperl.com/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz
Fetching with LWP:
http://cpan.strawberryperl.com/modules/03modlist.data.gz
Creating database file ...
Done!
XML::LibXML is up to date (2.0124).`

Comment: There is a build folder, but it's empty.

Comment: An update to this: I've discovered that I can run scripts using LibXML from the hard drive, but not on the network. I don't know if that sheds any more light on what the problem might be?